# You cannot run CocoaPods as root

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods

when I execute `sudo cordova requirements` on my cordova project I get this response:

```
Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed [object Object]
ios-deploy: installed [object Object]
CocoaPods: not installed 
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

But I already installed successfully cocoapods:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Name:~ username$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.5.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.5.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

MacBook-Pro-di-Name:project-cordova username$ pod --version
1.5.3
```

I looked for a similar problem in other posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029690/ionic-v2-you-cannot-run-cocoapods-as-root-error) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190064/cant-run-sudo-pod-install-after-updating-to-cocoapods-0-32-1-with-error-you-ca). If I try the second solution I get

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Name:project-cordova username$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
chown: /Users/username/Library/Caches/CocoaPods: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro-di-Name:project-cordova username$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cocoapods
chown: /Users/username/.cocoapods: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro-di-Name:sbc-cordova username$ sudo chown -R $USER ./Pods
chown: ./Pods: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to update Ruby version on my Mac. Nothing worked for me. I have Sierra (10.12.3) and last Cordova version (8.0.0), any idea to solve this problem? Thanks in advance